# Power Automate: How to update a Sharepoint list with a lookup column (string)?

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

I want to copy all of the items from a SharePoint list, which can be named Sourcelist, to another Sharepoint list, which can be called Destinationlist, with an automated flow. Both of the lists have two columns, Title (single text line) and Parent (lookup column). Parent is supposed to lookup values from Title column in the same list. I can't update the list with the lookup columns value, it is empty or I get error messages.

To start, I have chosen the Manual trigger action, and follow it with a Get Items action, which collects all of the meta data from my Sourcelist.

After, I selected a Apply to each loop and inside it I add Create items action in Destinationlist, where I only fill the Title column with the dynamic content [Title] from the Sourcelist.

Outside the loop, I perform another Get items action where I instead retrieve the meta data from the new list, Destinationlist.

Lastly I have a Apply for each action with the input from the previous actions [body/items] and inside the loop there is a Update item action. I chose my Destinationlist and put the [ID] in the unique identifier field and then also in the Parent Id field, I put [Parent Id] from dynamic.

I get an error message saying that it can't find the item in the Update items action which made me believe I had the wrong input. All the other actions was successful.

[image]

---

If I instead chose the [ID] and [Parent Id] from Sourcelist, then I will get the same message.

---

I tried with [ID] from the Destinationlist and [Parent Id] from the Sourcelist. Still the same error.

---

Before I also tried to add the value [Parent Id] in the create items action and skipping the whole update item action and the flow doesn't fail. However, in my Destination list the lookup column Parent is blank. When I look into the output of the create items action, I see that there is a parent Id being collected and also a parent value. The value is the exact same as the Id and not the actual value that was expected, which is referring to one of the items in the Title column. Is it a problem with it being the type string?